# How to get three different conditional SUMs column from single column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table called "revenue" and I need to find the below output. Would be grateful if anyone can help me to **Run a SQL Query** for this.

Table: **Revenue**

**See Table Revenue -->** https://doc-0k-bo-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha27nks08i3narb2038acg5vov0s6322/sghl1t4fla4qh5hgq9qhit6c8p5nelri/1520856000000/04225327153156048323/04225327153156048323/1nW4X0PD7Lqlax0bNdja9w0FhNt1syj0H?e=download&nonce=m41sn7c5m22nc&user=04225327153156048323&hash=omb49s8io4dmdgkaht89pneeao3t1v02

**See Desire Output -->** https://doc-08-bo-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha27nks08i3narb2038acg5vov0s6322/g4tuulvo1ve3dtpsdi4nd008nijv3jm6/1520856000000/04225327153156048323/04225327153156048323/1zbmBOzMedCDybbWbhib20ws1G1s3gucE

where,
**Monthly_Sale** - Total sales in respective months (Jan 2016 + Jan 2017)
**Quarterly_Sale** - Total sales in respective quarters
**Yearly_Sale** - Total sales in respective years.

**NEED HELP TO WRITE SQL TO GET THIS OUTPUT**

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.)

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags.  That doesn't really help the question much though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual formatted data are here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IGNQhd7ccIOOkZAv80q7FuDx3zSXNdW_XfGaS5BDytE/edit?usp=sharing